# Angular proxy to external API is not working

Tags: angular, proxy, angular-cli, http-proxy

I followed the instructions step by step, but requests are still not proxied.

Using Angular 14

```
"@angular/animations": "^14.1.0",
    "@angular/cdk": "^14.1.1",
    "@angular/common": "^14.1.0",
    "@angular/compiler": "^14.1.0",
```

`GET /api/v2/employees`

```
module.exports = {
  '/api/v2/employees': {
    target: 'https://***.***.**.**:18000',
    secure: false,
    logLevel: 'debug',
    changeOrigin: true,
    pathRewrite: {"^/api" : "https://***.***.**.**:18000"}
  }
};
```

**angular.json**

**"options"** priperty was not there by default, I have added

```
 "serve": {
          "builder": "@angular-devkit/build-angular:dev-server",
          "options": {
            "browserTarget": "coding-exercise:build:build",
            "proxyConfig": "src/proxy.conf.json"
          },
          "configurations": {
            "production": {
              "browserTarget": "coding-exercise:build:production"
            },
            "development": {
              "browserTarget": "coding-exercise:build:development"
            }
          },
          "defaultConfiguration": "development"
        }
```

**package.json**

```
"start": "ng serve --proxy-config=proxy.conf.json",
```

getting below error while running the application using 'npm start'

```
- Generating browser application bundles (phase: setup)...An unhandled exception occurred: Proxy configuration file D:\Work\coding-exercise\src\proxy.conf.json does not exist.
See "C:\Users\nagar\AppData\Local\Temp\ng-cTH8d9\angular-errors.log" for further details.
| Generating browser application bundles (phase: setup)...
```

Help me where I am doing wrong.

Answer (score 0):

`proxy.conf.json` is usually at the top level you're pointing to your src folder in your `angular.json`. remove it and then run `npm start`

Comment: Djebarri Amazigh thanks for reply. I have removed it but still same error.